# Only last Customview is showing inside a Tableview

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout

I have successfully created a TableLayout with a TableRow and some TextViews. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="A"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="B"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But, when I make a TableLayout with a TableRow with a Customview, it only shows the last CustomView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow>
    <MyFirstView
        android:id="@+id/MyFirstView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff400" />
    <MySecondView
        android:id="@+id/MySecondView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#0045ff" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The view works fine in a LinarLayout, is there something im missing?

Comment: Make the `android:stretchColumns="1"` Equal to `android:stretchColumns="2"` and try

Comment: 0 shows the first, 1 shows the second, 2 shows a blank screen. Removing it shows a blank screen, but setting both with the layoutwidth 100dp shows both. How do I set them to 50% width? I expected the table to format that for me

Comment: I need to understand, Why are you using a <TableLayout> in the first place. You can do the 50% thingy with Constraint Layout

Comment: this snipped shows how to set the width 50%
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight=".50"

Answer (score 0):

so we can do 50% percentage by:

```
<TableRow>
    <MyFirstView
        android:id="@+id/MyFirstView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff400" />
    <MySecondView
        android:id="@+id/MySecondView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0045ff" />
</TableRow>
```

Good luck )